# Function callback in event binding, w/ and w/o parentheses

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started with my first Python program and ran into a pretty strange issue with function callback. Here is the code that matches my expectation:

```
from tkinter import *

def say_hello():
    print('hello')

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='say hello', command=say_hello).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now if I add parentheses to the function name

```
Button(root, text='say hello', command=say_hello()).pack()
```

'hello' will be printed only once when the program starts, but nothing further happens when the button is clicked. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you add parentheses, you *call* the function (immediately printing "hello"), and its return value (not the function itself) is used as the callback.

The return value of `None` is a valid callback, indicating that there *is* no callback function for the `Button`. If `say_hello` returned, say, an `int`, you will probably get an error when you click the button to the effect that an `int` is not a callable value.

Answer (score 1):

`say_hello` is function. In 1st case you're providing it as argument, saying "Here's button, her's function `say_hello`. Execute (call) this function when you're pressed".

2nd case — if you're writing parentheses after function, this is the function call. So you're not providing your button with something to call later, but giving raw value instead.

The idea of callbacks overall — you provide something callable (function `say_hello` in your case) to object (`Button` in your case), so that object can *call back* in future, when it decides to do so (in your case, when pressed)