# Struggling with binding on tags in tkiner text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, bind

I'm struggling a bit with the text widget in the tkinter module.
I have added tags that I try to bind a function to.

Regardless of how I type it, it happens one of two things. Either I can click in the text widget but the only function popping up is for the last item regardless of where i click. Number two that happens is that it just spews out all functions automatically.

Did an edit on the original post and removed the coding i've typed. Have made the same function calls here as I had in the original coding (less 15k of code that's unecessary here):

```
 #!/usr/bin/en python
 # *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

 import platform as platform
 from tkinter import *

 class guidelen:
      def __init__(self, master):
           self.master = master
           self.master.title("programmet")
           self.master.geometry("400x400")

           self.populate()

      def populate(self):
           self.meny = Menu(self.master, tearoff=0)
           self.startmeny = Menu(self.meny, tearoff=0)
           self.startmeny.add_command(label="Avslutt",command=self.master.quit)
           self.meny.add_cascade(label="Start", menu=self.startmeny)
           self.master.config(menu=self.meny)
           self.tekstfelt = Text(self.master)
           self.tekstfelt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)



      setninger = ["første setningen","andre setningen","tredje setningen"]
           start = 0
           posisjon = 1
           while start < len(setninger):
               pos = str(posisjon) + ".0"
               b = len(setninger[start])
               pos2 = str(posisjon) +"."+ str(b)
               setning = setninger[start] + "\n"
               self.tekstfelt.insert(pos, setning)
               setning.replace("\n","")
               self.tekstfelt.tag_add(setning, pos, pos2)
               self.tekstfelt.tag_bind(setning, "<Button-1>", self.utskrift2(start))
               print(start)
               posisjon += 1
               start += 1

       def utskrift(self, event):
           print("Prøver tag bindingen")

       def utskrift2(self, event):
           if event == 0:
               print("Taggen til første linjen")
           if event == 1:
               print("Taggen til andre linjen")
           if event == 2:
               print("Taggen til tredje linjen")


 if __name__ == "__main__":
       start = Tk()
       guidelen(start)
       start.mainloop()
```

so regardless of how i alter the function, it always gives the same bind on all items in the text widget or it just spews out all bindings/function calls automatically.

Is there any out there that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-understand-chlosure-in-a-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494089)

Comment: Thanks I checked it out. It doesn't work when I coded it in. The bindings just became unresponsive (nothing came up on the screen and nothing happened when i clicked with the mouse in the appropriate fields).

Comment: without the lambda in place, it just executes the command given - one for each time it's binded.

I still scratching my head about what's going on

Comment: ***It doesn't work when I coded it in***: [Edit] your example and show your attempt.

Comment: have edited it now. Have made the same function calls as the original. Might be easier for you to read it although some text is in norwegian. thanks

Comment: You have remove the `lambda...`, therefore you have to understand: [function-callback-in-event-binding-w-and-w-o-parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421018). Can't run your example as you have multiple indentation errors, please fix it.

Comment: true i did remove the lambda. will try to fix the indentation errors but i'm not too accustomed to this site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
self.tekstfelt.tag_bind(setning, "<Button-1>", self.utskrift2(start))
```

It has the same behavior as this code:

```
result = self.utskrift2(start)
self.tekstfelt.tag_bind(setning, "<Button-1>", result)
```

Do you see the problem? You need to pass a *callable* to the binding, and your function isn't returning a callable.

The solution is to use something like [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda) or [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). I prefer `lambda` mainly because it doesn't require an extra import. Using `lambda`, you need for the function to accept the `event` passed by tkinter, and you also need to pass in the start value. It would look something like this:

```
self.tekstfelt.tag_bind(setning, "<Button-1>", lambda event, start=start: self.utskrift2(start))
```

Since you are calling `utskrift2` with a single argument, and that argument is the `start` value rather than the `event`, you need to redefine `utskrift2` to look like this:

```
def utskrift2(self, start):
    if start == 0:
        print("Taggen til første linjen")
    if start == 1:
        print("Taggen til andre linjen")
    if start == 2:
        print("Taggen til tredje linjen")
```

Comment: thanks Bryan. It helped a lot with your explanation and code example