# How do I call self in tkinter button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command, self

I was creating a sort of button-based paint with tkinter, so I wanted to give every button a command to paint itself.

> ```
>      for i in range(xc*yc):
>
>              grid.append(Button(wn,text="    ",bg="white",padx=5,pady=5))
>
>              grid[-1].config(command = paint(i))  <--????
>
>              grid[-1].place(x= (i%xc) * 30 +60, y = (math.floor(i/xc) * 30)+30)
> ```

The problem is that every button recieves the command "paint(i)" with the final value of i, so everytime it paints the last button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function-callback-in-event-binding-w-and-w-o-parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421018)

Comment: Your code would not have the mentioned output because `paint(i)` will be executed when it is being assigned to `command` option.  Your mentioned output will happen when `grid[-1].config(command=lambda: paint(i))` is used instead.  To fix the issue, use `grid[-1].config(command=lambda i=i: paint(i))`.

Answer (score -2):

Use root.update() method forecefully updates UI.so you can use that to see every iteration of for loop , if you call it inside that

Comment: But how do I see the iterations?

Comment: use this inside for loop, so UI will update each iteration of for loop

Comment: send a block of working code block , then i will check for errors

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like

```
for i in range(xc*yc):
    button = Button(wn,text="    ",bg="white",padx=5,pady=5)
    grid.append(button)
    button.config(command = paint(i, button)) # note the additional reference to button here!
    button.place(x= (i%xc) * 30 +60, y = (math.floor(i/xc) * 30)+30)
```

would be helpful.

Comment: Sadly it always calls the last button :(